# When creating a xUnit test project, many errors immediately appear

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, xunit

When creating a xUnit test project, or installing xUnit via NuGet, a huge number of errors immediately appear, as in the photo. At the same time, when I create exactly the same (on .NET 6) xUnit test project or install xUnit via NuGet but on another device, then everything works fine there. Visual Studio reinstalled.

[image: xUnit errors screenshot]

UPD:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>_1t</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\1r\1r.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: From your question it is not clear what the difference is between "xUnit test project" and "(on .NET 6) xUnit test project"

Comment: @Marco Yes, the problem is that when creating a xUnit project in Visual Studio, 19 errors immediately appear, while I do not have such packages installed, but it complains that these packages cannot work on .NET 6

Comment: could you add the contents your csproj  file to the question please?

Comment: @Marko Added .csproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. It turned out that there was 1 component of the .net 6 sdk missing on this computer, which is installed separately from VS. Installation links are here https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/windows ?tabs=net70 .